# MySQL sub-query issue

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT *
  FROM content
  WHERE topic='$id' AND active='1'
  ORDER BY date DESC, id DESC
  LIMIT 4) a
ORDER BY a.likes DESC
```

I have this query. I want it to select 4 entries from `content` table, and sort entries as follows:

1. SELECT most recent entries. It means ORDER BY date(mysql datetime) DESC, id DESC.
2. From those 4 selected, order them by likes(mysql INT) DESC

When runing my query, it returns wrong results. It selects entries matching this criteria `WHERE topic='$id' AND active='1'` . It sorts entries by likes DESC, but it ignore this criteria `ORDER BY date DESC, id DESC`, so it shows me results with a smaller id first.

What can be the reason? Thank you in advance

Comment: Your internal select should not contain an order by cause it will be ignored once you order by with your global query

Comment: @Philibobby: this isn't true; MySQL will honor the `ORDER BY` inside the inline view; that `ORDER BY` will be applied prior to the `LIMIT` clause.

Comment: @spencer7593 is correct. A subquery with `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` will never ignore the ORDER BY.

Comment: @ypercube : If you use an order by in the global query it will... No?

Comment: No, it will not ignore. It will use the internal ORDER BY for selecting the 4 rows and then use the external ORDER BY for ordering/displaying the (4) rows.

Comment: Oh ok I get it, there is a LIMIT. Sorry about that! @ypercube is right.

Comment: The `ORDER BY` in the inline view query is honored, but once MySQL materializes the view query as a "derived table" (is what the MySQL documentation calls it), then it's just a row source for the outer query, just like any other table. There is no specified or implied "order" to those rows. As my answer indicates, the outermost query only honors the `ORDER BY` on the outermost query; no other sequence of rows is guaranteed.

Comment: This doesn't sound like an issue with the inline view query. Either the inline view is returning the rows OP wants, or not. If the inline view query is returning a "correct" set of rows, the `ORDER BY` on the outermost query specifies the order the rows are returned in.

Answer (score 3):

After OP edits, the correct query will be

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT *
  FROM content
  WHERE topic='$id' AND active='1'
  ORDER BY date DESC, id DESC
  LIMIT 4) a
ORDER BY a.likes DESC, date DESC, id DESC
```

Comment: @OlafDietsche, can you explain what he want?

Comment: I don't think either of these satisfy the specifications OP provided.

Comment: @spencer7593, see comment above.

Comment: Just edited my question. What i just tried is `SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT *
FROM content
WHERE topic='$id' AND active='1'
ORDER BY date DESC, id DESC
LIMIT 4)a
ORDER BY a.likes DESC`

But it doesnt work as well. The idea of what i want is 'select 4 most recent entries', then sort them by likes DESC

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, it doesnt work. First, i think the query ignores the desired priority. I want first to select 4 most recent entries. It means "select 4 entries and order them by date DESC, if dates are the same , order by id DESC" -> when having those 4, order them by likes DESC.

Comment: @ValeriuMazare, If you want to order the most recent 4 records by likes DESC, then your query is correct. But if you want to preserve the most resent order for records with identical likes, then my query does just that.

Comment: my query sorts entries well by likes DESC, but i dont know why, it sorts entries by id ASC, so is not that i want. Maybe i just need to ignore date column in this case, and just order them by id DESC first and then by likes ?

Comment: @ValeriuMazare, do you want to order by likes DESC then by ID DESC?

Comment: no. the most important condition is the actuality of entries. so, i thought that first i should select last 4 entries (order BY date DESC, then BY id DESC). And when i have 4 most recent entries, just order them by likes DESC

Comment: @ValeriuMazare, Great, your query does just what you want.

Answer (score 3):

The `ORDER BY` on the outermost query specifies the order of the rows returned. No other order of rows is guaranteed or implied.

From the original question (prior to the edit) sounds like OP wanted the rows returned in descending order by the integer value of the `likes` column. That is, OP wanted to specify:

```
ORDER BY a.likes DESC
```

on the outermost query.

---

The rows returned by the query will be returned in the sequence defined by `ORDER BY` on the outermost query. No other sequencing of rows is guaranteed.

If OP wants the rows returned in a specific order, then the list of expressions in the `ORDER BY` clause on the outermost query will need to be specified differently. For example:

```
ORDER BY a.likes DESC, a.date DESC, a.id DESC
```

--or--

```
ORDER BY a.date DESC, a.likes DESC, a.id DESC
```

---

The `ORDER BY` in the inline view will be honored by the inline view query; but once that inline view query is materialized, and is referenced as a row source by the outer query, that  ORDER BY is gone. The outer query is free to access and return the rows from the inline view (derived table) in any order it wants; the outer query isn't required to honor the ORDER BY on the inline view query; the outer query just sees the derived table as a row set, like any other table.

(This is assuming that "`likes`" is a column in the `content` table, and not a result derived from some other table. We don't see what columns your query is returning, because you are using `*` as the SELECT list.)

(If that isn't what OP is looking for, OP can elaborate on the requirements for the specified resultset. Everything else looks right in OP query, for getting the four "latest" rows within the inline view.)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:
SELECT *
  FROM content
  WHERE topic='$id' AND active='1'
  ORDER BY date DESC, likes desc
  LIMIT 4

You dont need another level of select to do order by.
```

Comment: @user2411275: it's true you don't need an inline view to perform an ORDER BY; but OP specifies that those four "latest" rows are to be returned in descending order by "`likes`" (which we assume is a column in the `content` table.)

Comment: thanks spencer. Valeriu Mazare -  You cannot work on the same resultset and want to order them differently. order by on the likes column would definitely affect the order of the values in the date column